# Vertical bar in Pokémon Go Gym display

Tags: pokemon-go

I've seen a few gyms that have, as well as the spots and crown icons that indicate the Pokémon in the gym, have a vertical line between some of the spots, as in the image below.

What does this line indicate?

[image: Screenshot showing a gym with six spots and a crown, with a vertical line between the fifth and sixth spot, highlighted by an arrow]

Comment: There can be several lines or even just one for a lvl 9 gym.... Or 3 in a level 5 gym I feel this is not solved

Comment: Not posting as an answer because it's speculative, but I believe the bars are related to gym fights ending because the attacker runs out of Pokemon. Some Pokemon in a gym show a message along the lines of "x battles won" (I'm using a non-English version, so I don't know the actual English term), which relates to the battles that ended with this Pokemon standing. Based on my limited observations, the bars could play a similar role and denote Pokemon where battles have recently ended with the attacker's complete defeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line indicates that the gym is above level 5.

It exists so that, at a glance, you can quickly tell the level of a gym just from the dots. Each dot represents a level and the crown represents one more. A filled dot is a Pokémon on the gym and the crown is the gym leader's Pokémon.

Comment: No, you can quickly tell the level of the gym by reading number to the right of level. It's useful to count how many Pokemon are in the gym should it not be full.

Comment: Or they could simply use a number, not some silly dots or bars. They managed to do it right with the gym level after all :D

Comment: While that is true, that doesn't change the fact that it's the bar's only purpose. Even if the dots are unfilled, the bar is still in the same spot. UIs aren't required to only show a value in one format.

Comment: Yeah, but when you have to ask a question about purpose of such simple UI element then something is wrong...

Comment: I think the bar makes it cleaner. A blank space would accomplish the same effect, however.

Comment: This is definitely wrong. I've seen gyms with as many as 3 bars all the way on the left of all spots and another one somewhere in the middle. I've also seen the bars change over time without the gym's level changing. And I've seen gyms at levels 8+ with no bars at all.

Comment: Perhaps things have changed in recent versions. I stopped playing after they banned all rooted devices.

If the answer needs to be updated, feel free to edit it or submit a new one.

Answer (score 26):

This line is a grouping line to show sets of 5. It is to make it easier to count the number of pokemon in a gym, because counting lots of little dots can be difficult on tiny screens in the glaring sun. If you see a bar, you know there are five pokemon to the left of it, so you only have to count the number of bars and the dots to the right.

Number of pokemon in gym = (number of bars * 5) + dots/crown to the right of the last bar.

Comment: A slight correction: "Number of pokemon in gym = (number of bars * 5) + dots/crown to the right of *_the last bar_" (or 'rightmost' bar)

Comment: When you say there are 5 Pokemon do you mean five slots? or will the bar shift if there is an unfilled spot?

Comment: @Aequitas I'm not actually sure. I'd guess it would actually be five slots instead of five pokemon, but I don't think I've ever seen a gym over level 5 with an empty slot in it.

Comment: @Aequitas Came across a 7 slot gym with only 1 Pokemon the other day, it does indeed have the bar still

Comment: @DasBeasto Which makes the whole 'you can glance at the bar when it's sunny' thing pointless because you could just _read_ the gym level lol

Comment: Open slots in the gym without Pokemon are represented by greyed-out or unfilled dots. They're definitely represented in that part of the display, but they're just not a solid white.

Comment: How do fights in these gyms work? Is it the same as low level gyms? Do you still need to defeat say....8 Pokemons just to eliminate the weakest one?

Comment: @MarioGarcia You don't have to eliminate every single pokémon in the gym. Even beating just few of them lowers the gym's prestige which will eventually lead to level decrease of the gym and kicking the weakest pokémon out.

Comment: Empty pokemon slots are also shown to the left of the bar. The bar's in the same position regardless of the amount of filled slots (you can test this by placing a magikarp on a gym and then powerleveling the gym with a lower CP Pokemon). As I stated in my answer, the bar only indicates that the gym is above level 5.

Comment: This is definitely wrong. I've seen so many gyms at levels above 5 with no bars that it's safe to say it's the exception if they have one exactly between slots 5 and 6. I've also seen gyms with 3-4 bars, some of them grouped together. They are definitely somehow game play related.

Answer (score -2):

The bar means that you only fight the first 5 as well as the most powerful as you can't fight more than 6 pokemon at a time.